# cocos2d-x Simulate click by coordinates

Tags: cocos2d-x

Using: cocos2d-x 2.1.1
I have game based on cocos2d-x, I should implement same code to this game which can tap on elements. Now I can receive and send to server all elements from scene coordinates etc...

Now I need to click on game scene using coordinates.

I tried with create `CCLayer` over game scene and call `ccTouchesBegan` function with coordinates, but elements which placed under this `CCLayer` never receive touch event.

Is it possible to simulate click by coordinates without change game source?

A lot of thanks

Comment: What you need to do: receive touch events, forward them to the code that handles them. Then when you simulate events you'll call the same methods. You can't generate touch events yourself.

Comment: No, I can't call this methods, because I collected all elements as CCNode and I can't cast this CCNode to custom class (I have class name only as string e.g "CustomButton"). And I can't modify game code, just include custom wrapper for invoke Touches for CCNode coordinates